# TelNet and SSH merits and de-merits

Tags: security, telnet

Telnet and SSH are the two ways to login to the remote servers.
SSH is must preferred than Telnet.
But in windows Telnet package is installed but not SSH and why we are more likely go with the third party tool like PuttY.

If SSH is available in windows how we can enable this? What are the merits and de-merits of SSH and Telnet?

Answer (score 1):

Telnet sends everything in plaintext, including user account details like passwords. It isn't even included by default in Windows Vista or later.

PuTTY may not be included by default in Windows, but it is so widely used (and also open source) that all of its problems are quickly found and resolved to make it safe to use.